# Rails Sunspot search for items tagged with the tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am working in Rails 3. 
In one of my model, I have

```
acts_as_taggable_on :hashtags
```

and for indexing I have

```
searchable :auto_index => false do
  text :tags do
    "#{hashtags.map(&:name).to_sentence}"
  end
  integer :tag_ids, :references => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, :multiple => true do
    [hashtag_ids].flatten
  end
end
```

And when I do Sunspot search for items tagged for this model

```
Sunspot.search(Modelname) do
  with :tag_ids, 1
end
```

the above doesn't list the items

But the same works for other models which has

```
acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

How to fix this issue. Also in taggings the context is tags(other models) and hashtags(the model with acts_as_taggable_on :hashtags).

Comment: is auto_index meant to be false in this case?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 searchable do
  string  :hashtag_list, :multiple => true, :stored => true
 end
```

Then this should return results

```
ModelName.solr_search do
 with :hashtag_list, ["tag1", "tag2"]
end
```